# Filer for Google Cloud Computing

Tags: filesystems, nfs, distributed-system, google-cloud-platform, glusterfs

I am looking for a filer for my GCE project. It should serve as a shared storage provider for some of my VMs.

Of course it should be fail-safe, H/A, high-performance, … ;-)

I was reading through https://cloud.google.com/solutions/filers-on-compute-engine, but this document is very vague. I was hoping to find some kind of best practices or recommendation on the web - but found nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A file server, or storage filer in the linked document, is a program you can install and run on Google Compute Engine as they provide you with a full linux experience.

To leverage a cloud storage solution you don't need to go to this far as you can use [cloud storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/) which should suit your need for long term storage of data.

If the data needs to be mounted (read only preferred) as a disk on every vm you can use [persistend disk](https://cloud.google.com/persistent-disk/).

In the docs there is a [flowchart](https://cloud.google.com/images/storage-options/flowchart.svg) to pick the best option for your use case, you can find it on the [storage options](https://cloud.google.com/storage-options/) page.